# Torrent client says able to connect yet port not visible

Tags: torrent

I am currently on a 3G connection that uses NAT. Till sometime I used to see that uTorrent client couldn't make new connections suddenly I see that it says it's able to make connections (am able to download and seed) but still the port is not visible. I can confirm that I have opened the port through my router.

What's happening?

[image: utorrent and browser showing port status]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All BitTorrent peers don't need to be connectable.

Even if a peer has no open incoming port and can't receive connections initiated from other peers, it still can itself initiate and do outgoing connections to peers that have a open incoming port. Thus, it's possible to create a connection between them and it will work.

That you have opened the port through your router is good, but you still need a open port thru the 3G NAT to be connectable.

Comment: Do you have information on how to use this trick to make a p2p node on Android. Does my node need to connect to a hub looking for incoming connections and thus establish a connection. Will my node be able to send data directly to the other node bypassing the server which was used only to establish the connection?